# Is it possible to align a particular structure member in single-byte aligned structure?

Tags: c, linux, alignment, arm, structure

I am using ARM. I got alignment fault due to read/write in odd offset(we knew ARM is 4 byte aligned). All the structs defined in my program is single - byte aligned like

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)    

typedef struct
{
   char a1;
   int  a2;
   char a3;
}a;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

I am trying to do

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct
{
    char a1 __attribute__ ((aligned (4)));
    int  a2;
    char a3;
}a;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

the gcc attribute **_*attribute*_ ((aligned (4)))** makes no effect.

```
Note :: The above code is not my actual code. sample scenario.
```

so I re-arranged structure member to solve the alignment issue. I want to ensure whether the re-arranging is the possible solution or we can make **_*attribute*_** to work on this scenario. Any other solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seem that the #pragma overrides the _ _attibute_ _. Is is possible to remove the #pragma? And use _ _attribute_ _ ((packed)) when necessary?

Comment: I cant remove #pragma.I m reading USB data like that. Those structs should be single-byte packed.

Comment: Ok, then you can set ((packed)) attribute only for thos USB structs, and remove the pragma.

Comment: The first member of a struct starts at offset 0, so it must have the same alignment as the struct itself.

Comment: so I cant use __attributes__ inside #pragma???

Comment: Of cource you can, but if there is conflict between pragma and attribute. Compiler can select only one of those to use. In this case gcc seems to use the pragma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely read/write char/int in byte-aligned structs on ARM, compiler take care about alignment. Single problem can occur with alignment issue is with the casting to 32 bit int like this:

```
char buf[5];
char *p = buf + 1;
*((int *)p) = 1;
```

Note: if you for some reasons like align some member (from begin of the struct) you can use following trick:

```
typedef struct {
    struct {} __attribute__ ((aligned (4)));
    char a1; // offset is 4
    int  a2; // offset is 5
    char a3; // offset is 9
} a;
```

Comment: Is it possible to align a struct member to 4-byte if that struct is single-byte aligned using #pragma???

Comment: You can: try to do this: int __attribute__((aligned (4))) a2;

Comment: Tried. no change in struct size. gives 6 only.

Comment: Note: I want to align a1(char), not a2.

Comment: No I change my mind. It's sounds like "impossible" to align integer in not aligned struct. Imagine that you have pointer to not aligned struct, how can the compiler have to calculate the offset of "aligned" member?

Comment: I like questions of this type.